# Currency API_key doesn't work in flutter App

Tags: dart, api-key, fixer.io

Here is the my code :
[image]

Here is my result :
[image]

What's the actual code for access API ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some minutes to read about how to ask questions. Don't include screenshots of text/code. Use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the [`Fixer API`](https://fixer.io/documentation) and there was no reference that says your api key should be in the header.

Change your URL to this instead:

```dart
String url = "https://data.fixer.io/api?access_key=API_KEY"
```